# Pin chat windows in Windows Live Messenger to Task Bar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, windows-live-messenger

Is it possible to drag/pin individual conversations in Windows Live Messenger on to the Windows 7 task bar.

Currently, I have the Windows Live program pinned, and I need to hover over that, and then navigate to a given chat window. This is, in my eyes a) redundant, and b) irritating.

If I close the Live program, I lose all my conversations.

I may be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to achieve what sounds like it should be possible.

I like combining the task bar icons, with the exception of Live chat windows - so it may not be possible.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to pin any of my conversations individually in the taskbar, just the program itself. The only thing that I can think of is just to keep that chat window open, so it's always up.